# MS Access: How print the design view?

Tags: microsoft-access

In Microsoft Access, how do I print the design view without going through the Database Documenter?

My goal is to just have a list of fields, types, and field descriptions for a table, nothing more.

Comment: What's wrong with the database documenter? Too verbose? And what do you mean "print"? Do you want a report, or do you just want the results in textual form?

Comment: Too verbose indeed. The minimal options give me field name, type, and length. But I also need description. If I check the "properties" option, I get far too much information.
The ideal would be just to be able to print the design view, actually.
With "print" I meant "print." ;) Textual or report. Doesn't have to be pretty.

Comment: Do you know VBA?

Comment: Yes, I have also seen a VBA solution. I was just looking for a quick and dirty solution. This isn't something I'll be needing on a daily basis. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have the table open in design view

1. Click `database tools` » `database documenter` » `all object types`
2. Select your table you want to print
3. In the 'Include For Table' area, remove all 3 checks from the boxes
4. In the 'Include For Fields' area, choose 'Names, Data Types, Sizes'
5. In the 'Include for Indexes' area click 'Nothing'.
6. Ok » Ok » `Close the Table?` » Yes

Then print

Answer (score 1):

Often wished for the same thing. Sometimes a screen capture can help, at least in seeing the information, even if it isn't cut/paste capable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the possibility to connect your computer with a monitor with resolution sufficiently high (i.e. a HD tv, through chrome miracast function), you can move the Access window on the big monitor and get a complete view of your schema in the design view.
Then you can take a screenshot of it.

If someone could build an app that emulates an extra monitor with the possibility to set its resolution, that could be used for the same aim.